# Javadoc - refere to a parameter from another point in the documentation something like @link

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a class called ErrorHandler that takes care of all error message. Currently I am writing the JavaDoc for this class an have a problem. In my class I have several different pulic constants that describle all different error types.

A few examples:

```java
/**
 * here I want to refere to parameter errorType
 */
public static void final String INVALID_COMMAND = "invalid_command";
public static void final String INVALID_NUMBER = "invalid_number";
```

These constants are used in my `printErrorMessage` method as a parameter to determin which error occured.

My method looks as follows:

```java
/**
 * Prints an error message according to the type of error that is appended.
 *
 * @param errorType type of error that occurred
 * @see #INVALID_COMMAND
 * @see #INVALID_NUMBER
 */
public static void printErrorMessage(String errorType) {
    //does stuff
}
```

My queston now is: When I write the documentation of the constants, how do I refere to the parameter `errorType`to tell other deverlopers that my constants are used as `errorType`?

If my intention is not working as I'm expecting it to. Can someone tell me how it would be done.

Comment: it should be `@param errorType`

Comment: @Tushortz `@param` would be used to document `errorType` for my method. However, I want to document my constants.

Comment: You could create an `enum` for your error types instead of relying on documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't link to the *parameter*, so you document the *parameter name* and link to the *method*.

```java
/**
 * For use with the {@code errorType} parameter in
 * calls to {@link #printErrorMessage(String)}.
 */
public static final String INVALID_COMMAND = "invalid_command";
```

Result javadoc looks like this:

> For use with the `errorType` parameter in calls to [`printErrorMessage(String)`](http://#).

---

As [commented by Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64685294/javadoc-refere-to-a-parameter-from-another-point-in-the-documentation-somethin/64686235#comment114372962_64685294), you should consider using an `enum` instead of string constants.

```java
/**
 * @see {@link MyClass#printErrorMessage(String) printErrorMessage(String typeName)}
 */
public enum ErrorType {
    INVALID_COMMAND("invalid_command"),
    INVALID_NUMBER("invalid_number");

    private final String typeName;

    private ErrorType(String typeName) {
        this.typeName = typeName;
    }
    public String getTypeName() {
        return this.typeName;
    }
}
```

```java
/**
 * Prints an error message according to the type of error that is appended.
 *
 * @param errorType type of error that occurred
 * @see ErrorType#INVALID_COMMAND
 * @see ErrorType#INVALID_NUMBER
 */
public static void printErrorMessage(ErrorType errorType) {
    //does stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [{@Value package.class#field}](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#value) to specify possible constant values for you method.

For example:

```
/**
* Prints an error message according to the type of error that is appended.
*
* @param errorType type of error that occurred
* Possible values:
* {@value #INVALID_COMMAND},
* {@value #INVALID_NUMBER}
*/
public static void printErrorMessage(String errorType) {
    //does stuff
}
```

Or if you have a finite number of possible errorTypes you can create an enum class with mentioned String constants as a value. This way you specify allowed values explicitly and no one can pass some random string as an argument.

Update:

As mentioned @Andreas, in the code above link is between method -> constant.
if you need the opposite relationship then you can use the following code:

```
/**
* Is used as a parameter for the {@link #printErrorMessage(String) errorType}
*/
public static final String INVALID_COMMAND = "invalid_command";
public static final String INVALID_NUMBER = "invalid_number";
```

Comment: OP is asking for a link **the other way**, i.e. for the *field* to link to the *method's parameter*.